# I18N properties file location in Struts

Tags: struts-1, properties-file

I have read a lot on this topic and concluded something is messed up either in my `struts-config.xml` or some location. I bet is the location of my file.

So I have a file called `MessageResources.properties`. It is placed in `/classes/MessageResources.properties` inside Eclipse IDE. Moving the file is just simple declaration in one configuration file, right?

My `struts-config.xml` is configured like this:
`<message-resources parameter="MessageResources" />` which by default points to `/WEB-INF/classes`.

It's very strange to get error like this: `javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Missing message for key "label.search.name" in bundle "(default bundle)" for locale en_US` ?!

I am new to Struts 1.3 (and even 2.x) and can't figure out where to place it to work flawlessly.

I use to get values from this file like:
JSP Standard Tag `<bean:message key="label.search.name" />` or 
JSTL's `<fmt:message key="label.search.name" />`.

I my opinion is really easy but I can't figure it out from long time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have message resources for the locale `"en_US"`, thus you should create a file

```
MessageResources_en_US.properties
```

---

and place it along with other resources for different locales.

Comment: There is no need to specify exact locale. I am just referring a file which have to used either using `<bean:message />` or `<fmt:message />`. I don't use any bundles to if I am not wrong to change languages. I just want to extract strings from that file.

Comment: Put the file in `src` or `resources` I don't know what are you doing.